# How to know if the code needs eval()

Tags: php, mysql

I have serval blocks in my CMS. some blocks contains PHP code and some HTML code. if I use eval to show the code while the code is an html code I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mob/main_content.php(17) :
>   eval()'d code on line 1

I need to add `print` or `echo` before the code.

can I build a function that can now if the code needs `eval()` or `echo()`

Comment: You should avoid of using eval. Just use require.

Comment: @RomanNewaza These blocks are dynamic the admin has the permission to add blocks and delete etc...

Comment: Bad design. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your actual question, you should use `require()` instead of trying to figure out if you should `eval()` or `echo()`. However, you should never use `eval()`. There are almost zero cases where `eval()` is the only way to do something. You should use a template engine that allows you to insert PHP code blocks into place and use that.

I personally prefer [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org), but there are plenty of others like [Smarty](http://smarty.net), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), and many others (those were the top few I found with a quick google search).

Comment: Thank you, but these blocks are dynamic and the admin will edit these codes. if I use smarty I will not be able to get data from database. right ? I will give an example, I have news block in my CMS, and the code is to fetch data from DB and show them in tables. how I can do this in `Smarty` or `PHPTAL`

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to feed a string as the source code of the block to evaluate to `PHPTAL` using `$phptal->setSource($template_code)` or to `Smarty` using `$smarty->display('string:' . $template_code)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no automatic way to know if something *needs* `eval()`. Just because it looks like PHP code doesn't mean it's intended to be eval'ed.

If you need to go forward with this approach, I suggest two possibilities:

1. Use different columns in the database for storing literal text and dynamic PHP; when the data comes from the PHP column you will use `eval()`.
2. Require the admin to mark up dynamic PHP in his input, e.g. `[php]...[/php]`. Remove the markup and then call `eval()`.